# FFmpeg: Remove Unsupported Subtitle Streams (MKV)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, video-encoding

I'm making a script which loops through a list of media files and then re-encodes them using FFmpeg. My issue is that I need to remove any subtitles that the MKV container doesn't support. This should be simple using negative mapping, however, the stream number is going to be different for each file. Here's my current command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "path/to/file.ext" -map 0 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -level 4.1 -profile:v high -c:a copy -q:a 100 -preset faster -strict -2 -movflags faststart -threads 2 -nostdin -stats "file.mkv"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that FFmpeg natively supports this. I managed to write out a script which allows for single or multiple occurrences:

```
stream_count=$(/usr/bin/ffprobe -select_streams s -show_entries stream=index,codec_name -of csv=p=0 "path/to/file.ext" |& grep -cE 'Subtitle: dvd_subtitle|Subtitle: hdmv_pgs' || :)
if [ "$stream_count" -gt 0 ]
then
    stream_id=$(/usr/bin/ffprobe -select_streams s -show_entries stream=index,codec_name -of csv=p=0 "path/to/file.ext" |& grep -E 'Subtitle: dvd_subtitle|Subtitle: hdmv_pgs' || :)
    if [ "$stream_count" = 1 ]
    then
      exclude_stream=$(echo "$stream_id" | grep -oP '0:[0-9]{1,3}')
      exclude_stream="-map -$exclude_stream"
    else
      counter=0
      until [ "$counter" = "$stream_count" ]
      do
        counter=$((counter+1))
        excluded_stream="$(echo "$stream_id" |& grep -oP '0:[0-9]{1,3}' |& sed -n "${counter}"p)"
        if [ ! -z "$excluded_stream" ]
        then
          if [ "$exclude_stream" = "*$excluded_stream*" ] #If ffprobe returns encode errors within the streams, double results may be returned for the problematic stream which this circumvents
          then
            counter="$stream_count"
          else
            exclude_stream="$exclude_stream -map -$excluded_stream"
          fi
        fi
        excluded_stream=""
      done
    fi
fi
ffmpeg -y -i "path/to/file.ext" -map 0 $exclude -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -level 4.1 -profile:v high -c:a copy -q:a 100 -preset faster -strict -2 -movflags faststart -threads 2 -nostdin -stats "file.mkv" #exclude isn't wrapped as it invalidates the opening hyphen
```

If anyone has any suggestions to improve this script any further, I would love to hear them.

Thank you @LordNeckbeard for the suggested modifications to the ffprobe command.

Comment: I find it easier and more consistent to parse the machine-readable output than the human-readable output: `ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams s -show_entries stream=index,codec_name -of csv=p=0 input.ext`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thank you for the suggestion. I had to strip the loglevel flag due to the possibility of encoding errors on the found streams

Comment: You can omit `-profile:v` and `-level` and let the encoder choose unless you need to deal with a limited playback device. `-threads` is another you can let the encoder automatically deal with. `-strict -2` isn't needed unless your ffmpeg is old and uses the previously experimental built-in AAC encoder. [FFmpeg WIki: AAC](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) says the "effective range for `-q:a` is around 0.1-2. This VBR is experimental and likely to get even worse results than the CBR (`-b:a`)". I never did look into that so I can't comment on that statement.

Comment: `-level`, `-profile:v` and `-threads` are there intentionally due to the intended use of the script. Omitting `-strict -2` has caused problems in the past but admittedly I haven't tested it recently. Interesting about `-q:a`, I added it by recommendation. Thanks for the information!

Comment: I have removed -strict -2 and no problems have occurred. Thank you for the insight.